# Errors using a OneDrive Mapper script to map to SharePoint drives

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive, mapper, network-drive

We are using a OneDrive Mapper Script (that runs on start) to map to Sharepoint drives and are getting a persistent error (error 224, as it were) that claims that the trusted sites are not configured correctly and/or that a Windows update needs to be installed.

We are running this on a Windows 7 machine and we are using Sharepoint via Office365.

What I have already tried:

- installing a hotfix from Microsoft, but it turns out the computer already had the update.
- Re-entering the trusted sites (mycompany.sharepoint.com, *.sharepoint.com, etc)
- logging into our sharepoint site on IE & clicking "stay signed in" to keep the token active
- opening the sharepoint drive in explorer (using the 'open in explorer button on the site) prior to running the script.
- mapping to the drive using windows explorer (results in the same access denied error)

Any help you can offer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mapping the drives with Zee Drive? Zee Drive is a commercial alternative tool to the WebDAV drive mapping from Microsoft; it doesn't require Internet Explorer for authentication so you should not receive the 224 error when mapping the drives.

You can download a trial of [Zee Drive from here to map your network drives to SharePoint Online](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/).

Disclosure: I work for the organisation that develops Zee Drive